# C# XLWorkbook cell width

Tags: c#

I have an XLWorkbook but the cell widths are to small. I want to give a cell width by default but don't know how. This is the code where i think the styles need to be applied.

```
var workbookBytes = new byte[0];
                using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                    {
                        wb.Worksheets.Add(ds.Tables[i], ds.Tables[i].TableName);
                    }
                    wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                    wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;

                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        wb.SaveAs(ms);
                        workbookBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
```

Thanks in advance, your help is really apprecieated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it ClosedXML.Excel library?
Also, can't catch the moment where you are trying to set a cell width in your code sample.
May be it is needed to iterate the worksheets and you can select columns there. For example:

```
IXLColumn col = worksheet.Column("A");
col.Width = 10;
```

Assuming this is ClosedXML.Excel, I couldn't find 'Width' property for cell in that documentation [IXLCell documentation](https://closedxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cell.html)

**UPD:**
After your comment I tried this:

```
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
     for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
     {
         wb.Worksheets.Add(ds.Tables[i], ds.Tables[i].TableName);
     }
     wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
     wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;

     foreach (var ws in wb.Worksheets)
     {
         ws.ColumnWidth = 50;
     }

     using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
        wb.SaveAs(ms);
        workbookBytes = ms.ToArray();
     }
 }
```

And it worked, if no further actions with columns called.

Comment: Yes it is a ClosedXML library and i didnt put any code in there because nothing would work. all i could find was wb.ColumnWidth. But if i set it to 200 its doesnt change anything. Als it couldnt find the worksheet part in your code

Comment: You can iterate via worksheets like "foreach(var ws in wb.Worksheets)" or use LINQ to find any you want (e.g wb.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault()).
Can you change any column width like that? :
var ws = wb.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
var col = ws.Column("A");
col.Width = 20;

Comment: Thanks, i'll let you know tomorrow. I can't access my code right now